# The product of $\phi$ is a Schwartz function with $m \in L^\infty$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-space

If $\phi$ is a Schwartz function and $m \in L^\infty$, if the product $m\cdot\phi$ a Schwartz function?

The Hilbert transform is given by a multiplication with the $L^\infty$ function
$m(\xi) = -i\,\text{sgn}(\xi)$, ie
$$Hf(x) = (\hat{f}(\xi)m(\xi))^\vee(x), \forall \; f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$$

Is it true that $Hf \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$??

Comment: Why would you think $m\cdot  \phi$ is smooth?

Comment: I know that for $\phi \in \mathcal{S}$, the convergence 
$$\phi \ast P_y + i \phi \ast Q_y \rightarrow \phi + iH\phi \;\;\;\;\;\; (i)$$  holds, where $P_y$ is the Poisson Kernel and $Q_y$ its conjugate. In the proof of the identity 
$$(H\phi)^2 = f^2 + 2H(\phi H\phi)$$
for $\phi \in \mathcal{S}$, in Theorem 5.1.7 in Grafakos's book "Classical Fourier Analysis",  it was used that convergence (i) holds for $2\phi H\phi$. How can I have this convergence without the smootheness of $H\phi$??

Comment: $\varphi\ast m\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, but their product is not necessarily. For example, suppose that $\varphi(x) = e^{-x^2}$  and $m = 1_{[-R,R]}$.

Comment: I agree with Joe Mac ... but why do you want to prove that?

Comment: I thought it'be reasonable to prove that so I could justify the convergence (i) (comentary above) changing $\phi$ for $2\phi H\phi$.

Comment: My first comentary here is just a identity used to prove that the Hilbert transform is bounded in $L^p$ (Theorem 5.1.7 in Grafakos's book "Classical Fourier Analysis")

Comment: About this example given by Joe Mac: the product $m \cdot \phi$ isn't in $\mathcal{S}$ because you don't have the smoothness decay, right?